# Finding optimal value of parameters of the expected value of objective

Tags: probability, optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I have an optimization problem of the form

$$\underset{x_k}{\max} \sum_{k=1}^{N}\mathbb{E}[f(x_0,x_k,\gamma_k)]\\
\text{s.t.} \sum_{k=0}^{N} x_k =C
$$

The objective function has a complicated equation, because $\gamma_k$ are random variables with gamma distribution and although $f(x_0,x_k,\gamma_k)$ are concave functions of $x_0,x_k$, but I can not guarantee that $\mathbb{E}[f(x_0,x_k,\gamma_k)]$ are concave functions (most likely are not). All the variables and parameters are non-negative (if this helps, we have $f(x_0,x_k,\gamma_k) = x_k\ln\left( \gamma_k\frac{x_0}{x_k}+c_k \right)$ where $c_k$ is some given positive constant)..

The goal is to find the optimal value of objective function and the variables $x_0\cdots,x_N$. What can be done to find the optimal value of this complicated objective function?

Writing the Lagrangian

$$\mathcal{L}(x_0,\cdots,x_N,\lambda) = -\sum_{k=1}^{N}\mathbb{E}[f(x_0,x_k,\gamma_k)] -\lambda(\sum_{k=0}^{N} x_k -C)$$

and KKT conditions

$$\frac{\partial\mathbb{E}[f(x_0,x_k,\gamma_k)] }{\partial x_k}-\lambda=0 \\
\sum_{k=1}^{N}\frac{\partial\mathbb{E}[f(x_0,x_k,\gamma_k)] }{\partial x_0}-\lambda=0 \\
\sum_{k=0}^{N} x_k =C
$$

What can be done from here? Is there an algorithm to solve this? Is this the right approach?!

Thank you in advance.

================================Edit=================================

As suggested by @Golden_Ratio in the comments, we can bring the derivative inside the expectation like this

$$\mathbb{E} \left[\frac{\partial f(x_0,x_k,\gamma_k)] }{\partial x_k}\right]-\lambda=0 \\
\sum_{k=1}^{N}\mathbb{E}\left[\frac{\partial f(x_0,x_k,\gamma_k) }{\partial x_0}\right]-\lambda=0 \\
\sum_{k=0}^{N} x_k =C
$$

What can be done from here?

Comment: If the dominated convergence theorem applies, why not differentiate within the expectation?

Comment: Yes it is possible however it becomes actually harder, since the derivative have multiple terms and multiple expectations must be calculated. For example in one of the formulations $f(x_0,x_k) = x_k\ln\left(\frac{x_0}{x_k}\gamma_k+c_k\right)$ where $c_k$ is some known positive constant.

Comment: Doesn't the linearity of "E" preserve the concavity of the inside function?

Comment: @Red shoes, how can we prove that concavity will be preserved?! After we calculate expectation (if possible I mean) the function equation is very complex and I can't show that it is convex. If I can prove the concavity after expectation, it would be a huge leap forward.

Comment: Do not dig into the calculation. Just consider general expectation of a general concave function. Write the inequality of concavity the apply E to both sides